# Why does asizeof.asizeof(xxxx) fix a memory leak?

Tags: python, memory, memory-leaks

I'm attempting to find a memory leak. When I run the program, memory usage increases over time. After a couple of hours it is up to 15 GB.

In the process of trying to identify where the leak is occurring, I added the line within the main loop (which ends up running about 18,000 times):

```
print('size: ' , asizeof.asizeof(xxxx))
```

I figured that this variable might be what is getting bigger and so I wanted to monitor its size over time.

To my surprise, after I inserted this code, the program no longer leaks memory! It took several times longer to run, but memory usage stays under 800 MB the entire time.

This is completely reproducible -- if I comment this code, memory usage increases quickly, but if I uncomment it then apparently the memory problem is gone.

I also used muppy.print_summary() to try to identify where the leak is happening.

When the leak is occurring, this is what it looked like after about 600 iterations through the loop:

```
 types |   # objects |   total size
====== | =========== | ============
  dict |      788133 |    615.75 MB
  list |      274393 |     29.30 MB
 tuple |      255051 |     15.80 MB
 .....
```

and if I would let it keep going, these variables would just keep growing and growing and the dict would be in the GB range pretty quickly.

When I uncomment the ashift line, this is what it looked like after 2000 iterations through the loop:

```
 types |   # objects |   total size
 ===== | =========== | ============
  dict |       41481 |     39.44 MB
  list |       27925 |     10.83 MB
   set |       10615 |      3.97 MB
   str |       34373 |      3.00 MB
  code |       11848 |      1.45 MB
   int |       46761 |      1.07 MB
  type |        1179 |      1.02 MB
 tuple |        5553 |    582.78 KB
 .....
```

I can keep running it past 2000 iterations and the memory usage stays mostly constant. But without this ashift line, the memory usage increases linearly.

I am really confused why a call to measure the size of a variable would actually effect the program's memory usage. Seems like a version of Heisenberg's uncertainty principle.

Does anyone have any ideas of how this could be happening? This is with python 2.7.5.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does adding an explisit garbage collection suggestion into your loop solve the problem? Crazy speculation, but it could be possible that you have a circular reference that somehow that print statement is allowing the GC to collect.

Comment: That was one thought I had as well, so I added "gc.collect()" in the loop. It did not fix the problem.
I also tried doing "print('size: ' , asizeof.asizeof(yyyy))" (different variable), and this did not fix the problem, so "print" does not fix it, neither does ashift with an arbitrary variable.
I've also tried just doing "time.sleep(1)" in the loop, in case the delay by ashift somehow effects things (grasping at straws here!) -- nope